# Update row with previous rows data

Tags: mysql

Good morning. I am stumped. I have looked at some examples and explanation but still stumped so I hope someone here can help.

here is my sql query.

```
SELECT         
calls.`date_entered`, `call_date`,`calls_contacts`.`contact_id`,days
FROM calls
INNER JOIN `calls_contacts`
ON calls.id = `calls_contacts`.`call_id`
ORDER BY `calls_contacts`.`contact_id`,calls.`date_entered`;
```

this returns

```
2014-05-25| |252525|
2014-05-27| |252525|
2014-06-03| |252525|
2014-05-15| |425254|
2014-05-15| |425254|
2014-05-17| |425254|
```

I need an output like

```
2014-05-25|2014-05-27 |252525|
2014-05-27|2014-06-03 |252525|2
2014-06-03| |252525|7
2014-05-15|2014-05-15 |425254|
2014-05-15|2014-05-17 |425254|0
2014-05-17| |425254|2
```

Where column 2 is populated with next rows column 1 date - field, and then column 4 is amount of days from first call to next call.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Remembering that rows in SQL have no order, define 'previous'

Comment: What do you mean, that why we order by and group by? or not?

Comment: He's right as the way mysql groups the records and takes the "grouped" value is NOT standardized and NOT guaranteed. So there is no "previous" and "next" terms in a group of rows. You need to define this by certain criteria/aggregate function like MIN() or MAX()

Comment: ok ok - byt can you min max just to get the previous one - theres no set id or any fields that run after each other except the date field? and then group by or order by contact id?